# Dictionary.Item in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am working with VB.NET since a year ago, and now I have to work in another project with C#, and i cant find this equivalence..

In VB.NET

```
Dim dictionary As Dictionary(Of String, Decimal)
Dim oPerson As Person = Nothing
Dim key as string = "SomeValue"

If dictionary.ContainsKey(key) Then
oPerson = dictionary.Item(key)
End If
```

What is the best method to do this in C#??

I have found something like this, but i dont know if is the best method to do it..

```
Person oPerson = dictionary.Where(z => z.Key == key).FirstOrDefault().Val
```

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/ try this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, decimal> dictionary = null;
Person oPerson = null;
string key = "SomeValue";

if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {
    oPerson = dictionary[key];
}
Dictionary<string, decimal> dictionary = null;
Person oPerson = null;
string key = "SomeValue";

if (dictionary.ContainsKey(key)) {
oPerson = dictionary[key];
}
```

Comment: `oPerson` is a `Person` but you are trying to assign `decimal` to this variable. Also `dictionary` should not be `null`

Answer (score 5):

May be something like this:

```
Dictionary<String, Person> dictionary = new Dictionary<String, Person>();

...  

Person oPerson = null;
String key = "SomeValue";

if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out oPerson)) {
    // Person instance is found, do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Dictionary dictobj = new Dictionary();
>             dictobj.Add(1,123);
>             dictobj.Add(2,345);
>
> ```
>        var a = dictobj.Where(x => x.Key == 1).First().Value;
> ```

Comment: Thats the exact same as what OP currently has

Answer (score 0):

OP answer is almost there already, if he can use Linq to get the data. Because the condition is only one key, so Where condition is enough, else you can use .Contains for multiple condition.

```
Person oPerson =new Person();    
var a= dictionary.Where(z => z.Key == key).FirstOrDefault();
if (a.Count() > 0)
{
   oPerson.ABC =  a.FirstOrDefault().Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this:

This will throw an exception if the key does not exist in the dictionary (exceptions are not a bad thing!)

```cs
var value = dictionary["key"] as Person;
```

If you want to check if the key exists first:

```cs
Person person = null;
if(!dictionary.TryGetValue("key", out person))
{
    //Dictionary did not contain value, act accordingly ...
    // ...
}
```

I want to stress that exceptions are not a bad thing, if your application will fail later on if the dictionary does not contain the Person, then by all means throw the exception!